# Left join in SQL Server like oracle left join(+)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, sql-server-2014

I have following query. I want left join like Oracle. I mean inner join with left join like below. Is there any way to write short cut left join in MS SQL Server like Oracle below is a sample of query

```
SELECT tbla.Name FROM
    tbla,tblb,tblc,tbld
    WHERE 
    tbla.ID = tblb.ID
    and tbla.ID = tblc.ID(+)--left join like oracle
    and tbla.ID = tbld.ID
```

Comment: **Don't use that!!** That syntax has been deprecated long ago - use **proper ANSI/ISO JOIN** syntax using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` !

Comment: And to emphasize this . . . Both SQL Server and Oracle support proper `LEFT JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 6):

You could use explicit joins:

```
SELECT    tbla.name 
FROM      tbla
JOIN      tblb ON tbla.id = tblb.id
LEFT JOIN tblc ON tbla.id = tblc.id
JOIN      tbld ON tbla.id = tbld.id
```